# Sencha Touch Sync Stores

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have two stores: localstorage and a json on the server, I'm trying to download data from json to the local. Please see what's wrong:

**/store/Notes.js**

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.store.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: "Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage",
    config: {
        storeId: 'Notes',
        model: "NotesApp.model.Note",
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'notes-app-store'
        },
        sorters: [{
            property: 'dateCreated',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }],
        grouper: {
            sortProperty: "dateCreated",
            direction: "DESC",
            groupFn: function (record) {

                if (record && record.data.dateCreated) {
                    return record.data.dateCreated.toDateString();
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**/store/Online.js**

> Ext.define("NotesApp.store.Online", {
>       extend: "Ext.data.Store",
>              config: {
>
> ```
>        storeId: 'Online',
>        proxy: {
>            type: 'jsonp',
>            url: 'http://server.com/made/qa.php',
>            reader: {
>                type: 'json'
>                //rootProperty: 'results'
>            }
>        },
>        autoLoad: false,
>        listeners: {
>            load: function() {   
>                 console.log("updating");
>                // Clear proxy from offline store
>                Ext.getStore('Notes').proxy.clear();
>                console.log("updating1");
>                // Loop through records and fill the offline store
>                this.each(function(record) {
>                          console.log("updating2");
>                          Ext.getStore('Notes').add(record.data);
>
>                });
>
>                // Sync the offline store
>                Ext.getStore('Notes').sync();
>                console.log("updating3");
>                // Remove data from online store
>                this.removeAll();
>                 console.log("updated");
>            }
>
>        },
>        fields: [
>                 {
>                 name: 'id'
>                 },
>                 {
>                 name: 'date_created'
>                 },
>                 {
>                 name: 'question'
>                 },
>                 {
>                 name: 'answer'
>                 },
>                 {
>                 name: 'type'                    
>                 },
>                 {
>                 name: 'author'
>                 }
>                 ]
>        } });
> ```

When I need to update I called `Ext.getStore('Online').load();`

But the console is not showing anything else after 'updating'.

I wonder what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ext.getStore('Notes').getProxy().clear()` instead works